# MochaJS setTimeout ES6

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, settimeout, ecmascript-6

While unit testing my Node.js app, I encountered a problem with Mocha and ES6 while using `setTimeout`.

Mocha said the test passed, but when I put in something else (to check the test, to make sure it works), it still says it passed, while it should fail.

Code:

```
describe('.checkToken', function () {
    let user = {};
    let token = repository.newToken();

    it('token has expired', co.wrap(function* () {
            setTimeout(function* () {
                let result = yield repository.checkToken(user, token.token);
                result.body.should.have.property("error");
            }, 1000)
        }));
    });
});
```

The other tests are all working and there is no problem in that case.

I've already tried an arrow function or a standard function in the callback of `setTimeout`, but it then crashes on the yield. `(Unexpected token)`

`checkToken` is a generator function.

Using:

- Nodejs v4.2.1
- Co v4.6.0
- Should v7.1.0
- Mocha v2.3.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `setTimeout` with a generator. It's the generator that you pass to `co.wrap` that will be ran asynchronously, and *it* needs to know about the timeout. You will need to `yield` the timeout (as something [yieldable](https://github.com/tj/co#yieldables), like a thunk or a promise):

```
it('token has expired', co.wrap(function* () {
    yield new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(resolve, 1000); });
    let result = yield repository.checkToken(user, token.token);
    result.body.should.have.property("error");
}));
```